# VS2010 Can't find assembly after it is renamed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, clr, .net-assembly, filenotfoundexception

I have a solution which consists, to put it simply, a Windows Forms Application project and a Class Library, both in C#. My library project was named `OldName`. Thus the namespace was also `OldName` and the generated file was `OldName.dll`.

I wanted to change the name, so I went into Properties, and changed the Assembly Name from `OldName` to `NewName`.

Building now generates a `NewName.dll`. However, the moment my application tries to access this dll, I get a `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException` (the dll contains my methods for binary-serializing some stuff): It claims that `Unable to find assembly 'OldName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.`Procmon.exe confirms that it is looking for the old dll (`NAME NOT FOUND`).

Now the strange thing is, if I copy the `NewName.dll` and rename it to `OldName.dll`, so that I have `OldName.dll` and `NewName.dll`, the problem persists. If I delete `NewName.dll` and only leave `OldName.dll`, the program crashes at launch with: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'NewName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.` This time, Procmon.exe reports that it failed a `CreateFileMapping` operation on `OldName.dll` because `FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS`, but it seems it gets the same thing on `NewName.dll`.

Changing the Assembly Name back to `OldName` fixes everything, but of course then the file name becomes `OldName` and I don't want that.

I can't for the life of me figure out where else it references the old assembly name. What could I be missing?

**SOLUTION:** My program allows the user to create a file, and then save it to the disk using serialization with the methods in my dll. It also Allows loading the file. Being lazy, I had made a test file once, and kept reusing it. Turns out, as @Tigran suggested, the old Assembly name still appeared inside the serialized data file, so when I attempted to load it from my program I was getting an exception because it couldn't find the assembly referenced *in the serialized file*.

Comment: How do you use serialization? binary, xml, data contract?  The answer in this question my help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950992/version-tolerant-serialization-how-to-find-assemblyname-of-the-original

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I **suppose** that in your program you use `standart .NET serialization`. Remember that in *that* kind of serialization `.NET` saves *type information* too. Complete type information, with namespace. That means if you change assembly name and recompile the *complete* type name will get mismatch.

If this is not what you-re doing, please clarify.

Comment: You're absolutely right. This solved the issue - I edited my question with details.

Comment: @Superbest: thank you for giving me a feeling of being useful :)