# WCF Streaming Convert Byte[] to Class Object

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, streaming, deserialization

I have a Streaming WCF service. It receives a stream of a serialized class called `ContentObjectData`. The bytes I receive in from the stream I have temporarily placed in an `ArrayList` as I don't know how big the `Stream` is and to be honest I don't know what to do with them anyway.

**The ContentObjectData Class:**

```
[Serializable]
    public class ContentObjectData
    {
     string Hash { get; set; }
     string Data { get; set; }
     string FileName { get; set; }
     string DisplayImage { get; set; }
    }
```

**This is the Service's Method that receives the stream from the client.**

```
[OperationContract]
        public void SendContentObject(Stream data)
        {
            ArrayList alBytes = new ArrayList();
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
            int count;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            while ((count = data.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                alBytes.AddRange(buffer);
            }
            long i = alBytes.Count;
            data.Close();
        }
```

At this moment in time I am sending an Image for testing using the following methods:

```
 private void btnLoadImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dr = OFD.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                foreach (string filename in OFD.FileNames)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ContentObject co = new ContentObject();

                        co.Data = LoadFile(filename);
                        co.Hash = Hashing.HashString(co.Data);
                        co.DisplayImage = co.Data;
                        co.FileName = co.Hash;
                        Stream stream = SerializeToStream(co);                        
                        SendContentObject(stream);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        private void SendContentObject(Stream stream)
        {
            NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None, false);
            // TimeSpan.MaxValue is interpreted with a rounding error, so use 24 days instead
            binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(24);
            binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
            ChannelFactory<RaptorStreamingHost> factory = new ChannelFactory<RaptorStreamingHost>(
                binding, new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://ccs-labs.com:804/"));
            RaptorStreamingHost service = factory.CreateChannel();
            service.SendContentObject(stream);
            ((IClientChannel)service).Close();
        }

        private string LoadFile(string filename)
        {
            return Hashing.BytesToString(File.ReadAllBytes(filename));
        }


        public static Stream SerializeToStream(object objectType)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, objectType);
            stream.Position = 0L; // REMEMBER to reset stream or WCF will just send the stream from the end resulting in an empty stream!
            return (Stream)stream;
        }
```

**I have this to DeSerialize but it doesn't make much sense to me:**

```
public static object DeserializeFromStream(MemoryStream stream)
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            object objectType = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            return objectType;
        }
```

How do I convert the ArrayList of Bytes (I guess DeSerialize them) into a New ContentObject?

**Update One**
Ah So close! 
Ok in this method

```
public static ContentObjectData DeserializeFromStream(MemoryStream stream)
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            ContentObjectData objectType = (ContentObjectData)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            return objectType;
        }
```

I have a problem. The Deserializer can not find the `ContentObjectData` because it is looking in the client's Namespace for `ContentObjectData` and not this Host's namespace.

Comment: what type is your object 'objectType' ( confusing name , it's not a type but an instance of some type).

I'm betting it's your ArrayList . just try to cast it .

var arrayList = (ArrayList)objectType;

Comment: The type is ContentObjectData

Comment: but you said you serialized an ArrayList , after desiralizing you get a ContentObjectData , R U SURE ?

Comment: No - I serialized the ContentObjectData and Sent it as a stream. On Receiving the stream - I saved the bytes into an arraylist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, don't use an [`ArrayList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to store your bytes.  Since `ArrayList` is non-generic each individual byte will be [boxed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) and a pointer to the byte saved in the array, which will use 5 (32 bit) or 9 (64 bit) times more memory than necessary.

Instead, you can copy the `Stream` to a local `MemoryStream`, then save the underlying `byte []` array:

```
    public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }        
    }

    [OperationContract]
    public void SendContentObject(Stream data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (data)
            CopyStream(data, memoryStream);
        byte [] alBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
```

Then later you can turn the `byte []` array back to a `MemoryStream` for deserialization:

```
    public static object DeserializeFromStream(byte [] allBytes)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(allBytes))
            return DeserializeFromStream(stream);
    }

    public static object DeserializeFromStream(MemoryStream stream)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        object objectType = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        return objectType;
    }
```

(Or, just keep the original `MemoryStream` and pass it around.)

**Update**

[`BinaryFormatter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) serializes full .Net type information (i.e. the [fully qualified type name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to and from the serialization stream.  If the receiving system doesn't have a type with exactly the same name, in exactly the same namespace, in exactly the same assembly, then deserialization fails.

If this is your situation, you have the following workarounds:

1. Extract a shared DLL containing the type in question and link it into both client and server; problem solved.
2. Write a [`SerializationBinder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationbinder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to map the type assemblies and names.  See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20178/Draw-with-Mouse#AdvancedBinarySerialization%3aDeserializinganObjectIntoaDifferentTypeThantheOneItwasSerializedInto9) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666511/how-to-create-a-serializationbinder-for-the-binary-formatter-that-handles-the-mo) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737602/cant-deserialize-with-binaryformatter-after-changing-namespace-of-class/13958180#13958180) for instructions how to do it.
3. Consider a different, more contract-oriented binary format.  [Bson](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeToBson.htm) is one option.  [protobuf-net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) is another, albeit one I have not used.  More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881766/can-strong-naming-cause-problems-with-object-serialization-in-c/881898#881898).

Comment: Added an update - you have almost got the thing workling, thanks !!