# How to deserialize and then put data into form?

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, generic-list, binaryformatter

**Goal**

I currently have a valid method of saving the information

I then want the program to load the saved state upon clicking a 'load' button after exiting.

I then want the program to display the data in the appropriate place

In the form I have two DataGridView's one for an employee and another for a supervisor.

=============================================================

**Method**

I have serialised two generic lists into a .dat file

```
BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();    
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
  bFormatter.Serialize(fs, employees);
  bFormatter.Serialize(fs, supervisors);
}
```

So far in the .dat file, I have 3 Employees and 2 Supervisors, and I am not sure how to extract the information and place them into the appropriate place

The lists are as follows:

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
List<Supervisor> supervisors = new List<Supervisor>();

Employee e1 = new Employee(MemberJob.Employee, "Name", MemberSkills.CPlus | MemberSkills.CSharp, false);
Supervisor s1 = new Supervisor(MemberJob.Supervisor, "Another name", false); 
employees.Add(e1);
supervisors.Add(s1);
```

=========================================================================

**Attempt**

I have had an extensive look around the internet and on Stackoverflow, but mainly it's irrelevant to my context or they are using the XML format which I do not want to use.

I assumed it would just be a case of replicating the `serialize` method and just changing the `bFormatter.Serialize(fs, employees);` to `bFormatter.Deserialize(fs, employees);` but I am stuck on what to do after I deserialize the list.

```
 BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
 FileStream fs = File.Open(FILENAME, FileMode.Open);
 object obj = bFormatter.Deserialize(fs);
```

The object then brings back the data I need but I cannot put the `object obj` data into a usable format, it is stuck in the `object obj` if possible I'd like to try to put it back into the `Employee list`

Comment: First, that is a bad way to store the data because you always have to save both lists every time.  Second. with a little effort, I bet Supervisor could inherit from Employee so that you only need to save one list.  After you deserialize the list(s), if you are using a DGV. you could just set them to be the DataSource and the data will show up automatically.

Comment: Are you asking how to populate the DataGridViews from the lists? Or how to deserialise into the lists that you need?

Comment: @Plutonix Supervisor does indeed inherit from Employee, how would I set them to be the data source? But before that how would I deserialize properly?

Comment: @Ciara - how to deserialise into lists

Comment: I have updated the OP. check the bottom of the post

Comment: Why not create a class that contains the two lists. Then serialize the class.

Comment: That means you could store Supervisors in the `List<employee>` at least for serializing and extract them with linq..  Set any list as the DGV datasource with `dgvEmp.DataSource = employees;` the DGV will create the columns for you and show the data in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Christmas present to you. Hope it helps. :)

```
namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        string path = @"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\myFile.dat";

        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Test
            List<Employee> eList = new List<Employee>();
            eList.Add(new Employee("aaa"));
            eList.Add(new Employee("bbb"));

            List<Supervisor> sList = new List<Supervisor>();
            sList.Add(new Supervisor("ccc"));
            sList.Add(new Supervisor("ddd"));

            SavedInfo savedInfo = new SavedInfo();
            savedInfo.employeeList = eList;
            savedInfo.supervisorList = sList;


            SaveToFile(savedInfo); //Save to file

            SavedInfo newSaveGame = LoadFromFile(); //Load from file

            foreach (var e in newSaveGame.employeeList)
                Console.WriteLine("Employee: " + e.name);

            foreach (var e in newSaveGame.supervisorList)
                Console.WriteLine("Supervisor: " + e.name);
        }

        public void SaveToFile(SavedInfo objectToSerialize)
        {
            Stream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create);
            BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            bFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);
            stream.Close();
        }

        public SavedInfo LoadFromFile()
        {
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                return new SavedInfo();

            SavedInfo objectToSerialize;
            Stream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
            BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            objectToSerialize = (SavedInfo)bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
            return objectToSerialize;
        }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    public class SavedInfo
    {
        public List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();
        public List<Supervisor> supervisorList = new List<Supervisor>();
    }

    [Serializable()]
    public class Employee
    {
        public string name = "";

        public Employee(string eName)
        {
            name = eName;
        }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    public class Supervisor
    {
        public string name = "";

        public Supervisor(string eName)
        {
            name = eName;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Edited based on jdweng's comment. I think jdweng is right.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike most other serializers, [`BinaryFormatter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) records the full .Net type metadata of the objects being serialized.  It also, as you have noted, [allows multiple objects to be written sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416423/serializing-and-deserializing-multiple-objects) in a binary file.

Thus, assuming you know what sequence of objects should appear in the binary file, you can call `Deserialize(fs)` multiple times on the stream, then cast the returned object to what you expect:

```
var supervisors = (List<Supervisor>)bFormatter.Deserialize(fs);
var employees = (List<Employee>)bFormatter.Deserialize(fs);
```

That being said, do any of your `Supervisor` and `Employee` classes have direct references to each other?  For instance, something like this?

```
[Serializable]
public class Employee : Person
{
    public Supervisor Supervisor { get; set; }
}
```

If so, *you must serialize both employee and supervisor lists in a single call to `Serialize()`*, because `BinaryFormatter` only preserves object graph relationships within each single call to `Serialize()` and `Deserialize()`.  With separate calls, the interrelationship will be lost.  To avoid this potential problem, you could package your lists up in a single root object such a `List<object>`:

```
var bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
var root = new List<object> { supervisors, employees };
bFormatter.Serialize(fs, root);
```

Then, to deserialize:

```
var bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
var root = (List<object>)bFormatter.Deserialize(fs);
var employees = root.OfType<IEnumerable<Employee>>().SelectMany(e => e).ToList();
var supervisors = root.OfType<IEnumerable<Supervisor>>().SelectMany(e => e).ToList();
```

By the way, serialization with `BinaryFormatter` may not be the best choice for persisting your data in the long term.  If you make any changes in your classes, you will need to implement [Version Tolerant Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  See also [Can strong naming cause problems with object serialization in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881766).  And the fact that `BinaryFormatter` construct objects based entirely on the type information inside the file can introduce security risks deserializing untrusted data.